# Best way to address selection bias when outcome cannot be randomized

Tags: logistic, bias, sensitivity-analysis, randomized-tests

I have an (low incidence) binary outcome compared between 2 groups. The intervention for group 1 is coming from a specific type of center (academic) while group 2 from a different center. It is not possible to randomize due to the nature of the intervention. What is the best way to address selection bias in my analysis? A multivariable model adjusting for significant confounders?

Comment: Do you know why the treated center was chosen to receive the treatment? Do you have pre-treatment data? Is the untreated center of a non-academic type?

Comment: Only those academic centers perform the treatment in the interventional manner. The other centers are mixed academic and institutional. Data has not been collected yet we are in the planning stage.

Comment: I don’t see a good way of doing this without some untreated academic centers.